# cache spark table in thrift server

Tags: caching, apache-spark

when using jupyter to cache some data into spark (using sqlcontext.cacheTable) i can see the table cached for the sparkcontext running within Jupyter. But now i want to access those cached tables from BI tools via odbc using the thrift server. when checking the thriftserver cache I dont see any table, the question is how do i get those tables cached to be consumed from BI tools?

do i have to send the same spark commands via jdbc? in that case, is the context related to the current session?

regards,
miguel

Comment: How did you check the thriftserver cache?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In order to have the tables cached to be used with jdbc/odbc clients via thriftserver i have to use CACHE TABLE from one of the clients, for exmaple from beeline. Once this is done the table is in-memory for all the different sessions.

It is also important to be sure you are using the right spark thriftserver. In order to know that just do a show table; in beeline, if you get just one column back you are not using the spark one and the CACHE TABLE wont work.

Comment: Pay attention, the cache can be in the driver itself, if you use dynamic worker allocation (because executor can be removed and re-spawned).